# sed substitution: substitute string is a variable needing expansion AND contains slashes

Tags: bash, sed

I am fighting with `sed` to do a substitution where the substitute string contains slashes.  This general topic has been discussed on stack overflow before.  But, AFAICT, I have anew wrinkle that hasn't been addressed in previous questions.

Let's say I have a file, ENVIRO.tpml, which has several lines, one of which is

```
Loaded modules: SUPPLY_MODULES_HERE
```

I want to replace `SUPPLY_MODULES_HERE` in an automated fashion with a list of loaded modules.  (At this point, if anyone has a better way to do this than `sed`, please let me know!)  My first effort here is to define an environment variable and use `sed` to put it into the file:

```
> modules=$(module list 2>&1)
> sed "s/SUPPLY_MODULES_HERE/${modules}/" ENVIRO.tmpl > ENVIRO.txt
```

(The `2>&1` being needed because `module list` sends its output to `STDERR`, for reasons I can't begin to understand.)  However, as is often the case, the modules have slashes in them.  For example

```
> echo ${modules}
gcc/9.2.0  mpt/2.20
```

The slashes kill my command because `sed` can't understand the expression and thinks my substitution command is "unterminated".

So I do the usual thing and use some other character for the command delimiter:

```
> modules=$(module list 2>&1)
> sed "s|SUPPLY_MODULES_HERE|${modules}|" ENVIRO.tmpl > ENVIRO.txt
```

and I still get an "unterminated 's'" error.

So I replace double quotes with single quotes:

```
> sed 's|SUPPLY_MODULES_HERE|${modules}|' ENVIRO.tmpl > ENVIRO.txt
```

and now I get no error, but the line in ENVIRO.txt looks like

```
Loaded modules: ${modules}
```

Not what I was hoping for.

So, AFAICT, I need double quotes to expand the variable, but I need single quotes to make the alternative delimiters work.  But I need both at the same time.  How do I get this?

UPDATE: Gordon Davisson's comment below got to the root of the matter: "echo ${modules} can be highly misleading".  Examining $modules with declare -p shows that it actually has a newline (or, more generally, some kind of line break) in it.  What I did was add an extra step to extract newlines out of the variable.  With that change, everything worked fine.  An alternative would be to convince sed to expand the variable with line breaks and substitute it as such into the text, but I haven't been able to make that work.  Any takers?

Comment: I don't think you "need single quotes to make the alternative delimiters work". Your example seemed to work for me. Are you testing it with that actual example? `modules="gcc/9.2.0  mpt/2.20";echo Loaded modules: SUPPLY_MODULES_HERE | sed "s|SUPPLY_MODULES_HERE|${modules}|"` Or do you have a different scenario where the modules have a pipe in them?

Comment: What's the actual contents of `$modules`? [`echo ${modules}` can be highly misleading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else), so try `declare -p modules | LC_ALL=C cat -v` instead.

Comment: There’s nothing obviously wrong with the version using double quotes and pipes. Prepend `echo`, removing redirection, and post that output, so we can see what sed is trying to execute.

Comment: If your templates have several substitutions to perform or more complex operations then you could directly use a templating language like PHP or ERB (Ruby).

Comment: @GordonDavisson  You might be interested in my update.

Comment: What is the output of `modules="$(module list 2>&1)"; declare -p modules` ?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

`sed` is not the best tool here due to use of regex and delimiters.

Better to use `awk` command that doesn't require any regular expression.

```sh
awk -v kw='SUPPLY_MODULES_HERE' -v repl="$(module list 2>&1)" '
n = index($0, kw) {
   $0 = substr($0, 1, n-1) repl substr($0, n+length(kw))
} 1
' file
```

- `index` function uses plain string search in `awk`.
- `substr` function is used to get substring before and after the search keyword.